# get last 10 rows from txt file and sort

Tags: python, sorting

I get the last 10 lines from the TXT file like this:

```
a_file = open("log.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
last_lines = lines[-10:]
```

Get the answer like this:

```
c
d
e
f
g
```

How do sort the result so that last line is on top?

```
g
f
e
d
c
```

Comment: You can reverse it: `reversed(lines[-10:])` or slice it backwards: `lines[:-10:-1]`, see the linked dupe for examples of both.

Comment: tzaman Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use reversed() to read a file line by line backwards:

```
a_file = open("log.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
for line in reversed(lines):
    print(line)
```